# Angular JS can't update data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller, which is responsible for adding product item to shopping cart. Everything is fine, the request is sending, getting response data, but I can't update the data in the html (see the image). 
I have tried to write it with `$scope.$apply(); $scope.$watch` But I am getting from `rootScope and $digest`

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

And if I don't use $apply, the data is not updating.

[image]

Here is my code.

```
<a href="">Pr: {{cart.count}} <br/> Summ. {{ cart.summ | number:2 }}</a>
```

---

```
shopApp.factory('shop', ['$http', function($http) { 
  return $http.get('/ajax/get_shop.ajax') 
    .success(function(data) { 
        return data; 
    }) 
    .error(function(err) { 
        return err; 
    }); 
}]);
```

---

```
shopApp.controller('ShopController', ['$scope','$http','$timeout','shop', function($scope,$http,$timeout,shop) { 
$scope.cart = null;
shop.success(function(data) { 
    $scope.cart = data;         
});
$scope.addToCart = function() {
    var pr_price = parseInt(angular.element("#pr_price").val(),10);
    var pr_id = angular.element("#pr_id").val();
    if( pr_price!= "" ){
        return $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/ajax/add_to_cart.ajax',
            data : 'pr_price=' + json_obj + '&pr_id='+pr_id ,
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        })
        .success(function (shopping_data,status) {
            if ( status == 200 ){   

                $scope.cart = shopping_data;    
                console.log(shopping_data);//everything is ok  


            }       
        }).error(function(err) { 
            return err; 
        });
    }       
};
}]);
```

Comment: can you provide sample [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)?

Answer (score 2):

In Angular, you should never update the DOM like you do here:

```
angular.element("#rct_success_alert").html('<div><a href=""><h3>Product Successfully added to your cart</h3></div><div>'+shopping_data.count+' Items</a></div>' );
```

Also you don't need `apply` here:

```
  $scope.$apply(function(){
       $scope.cart = shopping_data;
  });
```

Just assign it and Angular will bind it to the template:

```
 $scope.cart = shopping_data;
```

Your factory can be much easier too:

```
shopApp.factory('shop', ['$http', function($http) { 
  return $http.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/count/123/summ/234'); 
}]);
```

I have [created a JSBin](https://jsbin.com/lijotusucu/1/edit?js,output) that calls a JSON echo server, if you don't see results, go to `http://echo.jsontest.com/count/123/summ/234` in your browser and make sure it's not over quota.

Comment: The whole problem is $scope.cart = shopping_data; not updating the data

Comment: That's why you should try updating it with a data structure that does not come from the backend to sort out if the problem is on the controller side of in the JSON/with backend communication.

Comment: I have tried to set the $scope.cart  = {
    count : 123,
    summ: 98877.234
} , Still not working

Comment: Why don't you even look at the browser console to see if there are errors? I set up a slightly modified version (you need to include jQuery additionally to Angular if you want to read the inputs like you do) here: https://jsbin.com/loyabetezu/edit?html,js,output - It does not do AJAX, but sets `$scope.cart = { count : 123, summ: 98877.234 }` and works.

Comment: I am looking at the browser console, there is no errors, the error appears when I am running the $apply() function, in other cases there is no errors, not from server(AJAX). Also the jQuery is included

Comment: I have tried the way like you, but i need to run it when the response is come, The response is ok BTW. But just can't understand the problem why it is not working in http

Comment: "the error appears when I am running the $apply() function" - that's what I am talking about, you should not use `$apply()`.

Comment: Then why is it in the code in the question? And why don't you even include an example of the JSON you are getting?

Comment: I have update the question, I just forgot to remove the $apply, take a look please

Comment: See my update, I have created a JSBin that calls a web server and sets the cart with the result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your **shop** factory, you have either to call the success function in the service **or** in the controller not twice. Try something like this :

```
shopApp.factory('shop', ['$http', function($http) {

     var shop = {};

     shop.getCart = function () {
         return $http.get('/ajax/get_shop.ajax');
     };

     return shop;

}]);
```

And in your *ShopController* :

```
 shop.getCart()
    .success(function(data) { 
        $scope.cart = data;         
    })
    .error(function () {
        // Do Something Cool Here
    });
```